# What does "exponentially increasing" actually mean?

Tags: calculus

Suppose there is a variable $y$ which is dependent on variable $x$. If somebody were to say "$y$ increases exponentially with $x$", which of these do they actually mean:

1) Literally $y=e^x$

2) Some exponential relationship, e.g. $y=ae^{bx}$

3) They just mean that the increase in $y$ with respect to $x$ is "more than linear"

Comment: It's a little vague. It could mean 2, or it could (most likely) include lower order terms and mean $y\sim a e^{bx}$.

Comment: It is worth noting that $2$ also covers cases where it is $y=ak^{x}$ since by taking $b=\ln k$ you would have $ae^{x\ln k} = ae^{\ln k^x} = ak^x$

Comment: Many times, when people say that, they actually talk about asymptotic order of growth of the function wrt the growth of input. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: I'd use that to say increasing faster than $e^{|bx|}$ for some $b$. I'm quite sure many people say that $e^{x^2}$ is exponentially increasing

Comment: @user1952009 I don't know anyone who'd say $e^{x^2}$ increases exponentially. At most, you could stick a subexponential (polynomial, for example) factor in front of $\exp$ to have $\log y\sim bx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually means that the instantaneous rate of change of $y$ is proportional to $y$. That is,
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \lambda y
$$
for some constant $\lambda$. Solving this differential equation gives you $c e^{\lambda x}$, which is precisely the exponential function.

Comment: If $y = ce^{\lambda x}$, then isn't $\frac{dy}{dx}=\lambda e^{\lambda x}$? So actually the rate of change of $y$ is itself exponential?

Comment: @Karnivaurus $c$ remains in the front after differentiating. Notice that $c e^{\lambda x} = y$, and yes, the rate of change is itself exponential, but you will have to define exponential first.

Comment: Ah yes, so isn't the derivative $c \lambda e ^ {\lambda x}$?

Comment: @Karnivaurus That equals to $\lambda y$.

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks. (Not sure why your answer was voted down by someone else...)

Comment: Downvoted because answer is not correct. The comments to op have more correct answers.